# Xilinx: .bit --> .SVF / .ACE

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ise

I've generated the bitstream file for my device, which steps should I take to compile the .ACE file, I could flash my device with?

I'm using Xilinx ISE 10.1 with Virtex2 over an VME interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done this, but a quick google shows that the helpfile details the process!

http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/isehelp/pp_p_process_generate_target_prom_ace_file.htm

Using the ISE "Generate a target PROM or ACE file" process.